# Is the collection of all cardinalities a set or a proper class?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is the collection of all cardinalities a set or a proper class?
Does anybody ever think about the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Collection of all cardinalities is indeed a proper class. To see this, note that there is at least as many cardinal numbers as ordinal numbers, because map $\alpha\rightarrow\aleph_\alpha$ is an injection.

Answer (score 2):

It is a proper class. There are several ways to see this. One is: suppose $X$ were the set of all cardinals (=initial ordinals). The ordinals - in particular, the cardinals - are well-ordered, so we may add them together (indexed by this well-order) to form a single "super-cardinal;" but it's easy to check that this super-cardinal is larger than any element of $X$.

This is essentially the same reasoning as the Burali-Forti paradox http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox, which shows that the class of *ordinals* is a proper class.

Comment: Your argument requires, in explicit way, well ordering principle, which is independent of $ZF$. You might want to point this out in the answer.

Comment: No it doesn't - the initial ordinals are all **ordinals**, so they're well-ordered with no assumption.

Comment: But cardinals need not be initial ordinals. :-)

Comment: In the absence of choice, one needs to be clear what a "cardinality" is - I've shown that the cardinalities of well-orderable sets are never a set, so a fortiriori the cardinalities in general do not form a set, whatever we take a "cardinality" to be.

Answer (score 0):

The collection of all cardinal numbers is a proper class.  If it were a set $X$, then $(\sup X)^+$ would be a cardinal number greater than every element of $X$, which is a contradiction.

(The supremum of a set of cardinals is given by its union, and the cardinal successor $\kappa^+$ of a cardinal $\kappa$ is defined as the [Hartogs number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number) of $\kappa$.)